# Regex to split string at any white-space character but to isolate any line break character

Tags: javascript, regex

It's always such a brainteaser for me but I simply can't find that out on my own...

I'd like to split a string with any white-space character BUT to isolate any `\n` occurrence.

For instance:

**input:**

```
"Regex expressions make your life...↵easier!"
```

**ouput:**

```
"Regex"
"expressions"
"make"
"your"
"life..."
"↵"
"easier!"
```

So far I've tried something like `/s|[^\n]`  but it didn't turn out to be very conclusive.

Any clue?

Comment: You can use split method

Comment: @ant: I tried but failed, I would love to see an example :)

Comment: a single space is what you required..no need to use `\s`

Comment: @ant sure but that's not my question... the question is about the argument to give to that method not the method itself :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: `/(\S+|\n)/g`

```
var s = 'Regex expressions make your life...\neasier!';
s.match(/(\S+|\n)/g)
```

Comment: Hi! Hum close enough.... but it looks this one manages to catch the line break but it also isolates all the white-space characters. I'd like the latter ones to be filtered out indeed.

Comment: I don't understand, what does mean whitespace isolating?

Comment: Your solution gives me that:

"Regex" | " " | "expressions" | " " | "make" | " " | "your" | " " | "life..." |  "\n" | "easier!"
Instead of "Regex" | "expressions" | "make" | "your" | "life" | "\n" | "easier!"

Comment: @user966964 I've tested in firefox and chrome, and i did not saw the spaces in selection. Where do you find they?

Comment: I'm using chrome: http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/7122/screenshot20121130at123.png

Comment: And this is what I'm aiming for: http://img820.imageshack.us/img820/7122/screenshot20121130at123.png

Comment: And why you've decided to use split? **Match** is searching for match, and you searching for delimiters, that is not my idea.

Comment: Hum a moment of weakness I guess! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

This works:

`[^\S\n]+`

*Not (NOT-Whitespace or Newline)* wich equals *Whitespace AND not newline* (DeMorgan)

And if i get your "isolating" right, try this: `([^\S\n]|\n)`

input:

```
this is a test
regex
```

preg_split:

```
Array
(
[0] => this
[1] => is
[2] => a
[3] => test
[4] => 
[5] => regex
)
```

hmm, but that will be the same as `\s` (`not \n or \n` is obsolet, leaves `^\S` - which is `\s` - so what you mean by "isolating"?

Comment: Hum it's closer but still doesn't look to work... at least not on Chrome: http://img502.imageshack.us/img502/7122/screenshot20121130at123.png

Comment: indeed that is a special "behavior" if using javasscript's split function: http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/regtest.htm (uses Javascript)